# when DB field contains & it showed &amp; in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I viewed a lot of previous questions without getting a clear answer.

I have this example which is shown in textbox comes from DB:

> Christian Henson Jeeves  &amp ;  Jemima

and it should be:

> Christian Henson
>   Jeeves & Jemima

Please I need a function or some code to change it before showing it in textbox

Comment: so the condition is always after & add space ?

Comment: tell me the table structure

Comment: Are you sure your database contains a `&`, or is it a `&amp;`? You may want to investigate why that wrong value is in your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourTextBox.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(YourStringFromDatabase);
```

Comment: Thank you very much